# Partially rename an XML node

Tags: xslt

Given the XML snippet:

```
<rng:define name="starting_limits">
   <rng:element name="limits">
      <rng:ref name="Limits"/>
   </rng:element>
</rng:define>
```

I want this:

```
<rng:define name="limits">
   <rng:element name="limits">
      <rng:ref name="Limits"/>
   </rng:element>
</rng:define>
```

For all define elements. So I just want to remove the "starting_" prefix for all define element name attributes in the infoset.

Comment: `@starting_*` isn't actually valid syntax in a match expression. Also, in your XML, the attribute is called `name` and has a value of `starting_limits`, as opposed to being an attribute of the form `starting_limits="..."`. Do you actually want to rename the attribute, or just change its value? It would help if you showed the output you expect here. Thanks!

Comment: I want to rename the attribute. I can see how to do that completely, but I just want to remove the first part and preserve the characters after the underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(., 'starting_')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., 'starting_', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

it matched all attribute start-with `'starting_'` and remove it from output

Comment: Thanks, but I want to edit the attribute itself, not the parent node's text.

Comment: @Qeebrato, I have edit my answer, you can also check TimC Answer with more description.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML the attribute is called `name` and has a value of `starting_xxxx`, so to match it, you would do this...

```
<xsl:template match="@name[starts-with(., 'starting_')]">
```

Or maybe this, in XSLT 2.0 and above

```
<xsl:template match="@name[matches(., 'starting_.*')]">
```

To remove the `starting_attribute` you can do one of the following, for example

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'starting_')"/>

<xsl:value-of select="substring(., 10)"/>
```

So, for example, your template may look like this

```
<xsl:template match="@name[starts-with(., 'starting_')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 10)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

If you wanted to make it more generic, and match any attribute, not just one called `name`, you could change it to this

```
<xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(., 'starting_')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 10)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```